# Is there a way to calculate the Froyshov $h$-invariant for Seifert homology spheres?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, 3-manifolds, homology, 4-manifolds, cobordism

In 2002, by using Floer theory, Froyshov defined the $h$-invariant for intergal homology 3-spheres, which is a surjective group homomorphism $\Theta^3_{\Bbb Z}\to \Bbb Z$, where $\Theta^3_{\Bbb Z}$ is the group of homology cobordism classes of integral homology 3-spheres with connected sum as operation. (https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9903083.pdf)

For Seifert homology spheres $\Sigma(a_1,\dots,a_n)$, there are some examples whose $h$-invariants are known. But is there a theorem or algorithm or formula concerning about a way to compute the $h$-invariant for a general Seifert homology sphere $\Sigma(a_1,\dots,a_n)$?

For the Ozsvath-Szabo $d$-invariant, a group homomorphism $\Theta^3_{\Bbb Z}\to 2\Bbb Z$ (which is also defined using Floer theory), there are some ways to calculate it for Seifert homology spheres (e.g. https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0310083.pdf), but I cannot find any results for computing the $h$-invariant for Seifert homology spheres.

Comment: Do you want this for something in particular? There may be tricks in specific cases to get around the lack of a nice algorithm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, not yet. The state of the art in computing instanton homology for Seifert spaces is in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.03800). This is like knowing how to compute $\widehat{HF}(\Sigma)$, which is not enough: you also want to understand $\widehat{HF}_{red}(\Sigma)$. More or less equivalently, you want comparable results for equivariant versions along the lines of the computation of $HF^+(\Sigma)$ for all Seifert spaces.

Such a computation does not exist in the literature nor do I believe it is forthcoming in the immediate future. You might get in touch with one of the authors of that paper. I know John Baldwin has put some thought into the equivariant versions of instanton homology and may be able to say whether or not the necessary calculations exist in his head.

Comment: It is expected but not known that d=2h.